# My slideshow won't slide to the next slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a basic slideshow and it won't slide to the next slide and I have set it to slide every 2 second. I have searched youtube, google and even on this site, but every method is not working.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div class="row" id="one">
    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="//images.australiazoo.com.au/azhome/steve_irwin_gala_dinner.jpg" style="width:100%">

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
          <img src="//images.australiazoo.com.au/azhome/petition_home_page.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="//images.australiazoo.com.au/azhome/ROBERT_IRWIN_WEBSITE_HP_BANNER.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

      </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

P.S The images are just placeholders.

Comment: Why are you involving the slide 2 and 3 inside the div .mySlides that involve the first slide?

Answer (score 0):

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrqd98c/)

There were some errors in **HTML** like misplacement and missing ending `</div>` tags and in script code as well. Try some more debugging for such cases.